# AngularJS: Generate a grid layout on the fly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a tabular structure where the number of columns in the rows should not exceed the width of the page. In case the number of columns in the row cannot fit into that row, they should move down to the next row under the same row heading. I wrote this code in AngularJS but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat='(key,val) in response'>
            <h4>{{key}}</h4>
            <div class="col-xs-1" ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val'>
                <a ng-href='{{function1(nestedVal)}}' target="_blank">{{nestedKey}}
                            <br>
                            <img id="graph" src='{{function2(nestedVal)}}' class="img-rounded"/>
                        </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The error that I'm getting :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: I'm not seeing `top` anywhere in the code.

Comment: Will the code actually do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If it does not work, no, definitely no. As Sergiu say, where is the "top" in the code you provide? We're missing elements to help you!

Comment: But there is no top in my code!

Comment: That's the whole point. An exception occurs in some code you are not showing us. There's no way we can help you only by seeing the code you are showing us.

Comment: I cannot show the rest of the code. However can you rewrite this code in that case to achieve what I'm trying to do? Assume no dependencies on rest of the code.

Comment: No, but you can rewrite the rest of the code in such a way where it simply demonstrates the problem on the JS side of things, and we can look at it.